# How to measure electro-mechanical coupling?

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors

I have mounted a piezo-ceramic ultrasonic transducer (MODEL # SMD10T2R111WL, Vendor Website: PIEZO CERAMIC DISC 10X2MM R 215 KHZ WIRE LEADS) under a plastic tank using epoxy. Please see the picture below.

[image: Ultrasonic transducer mounted under a water tank]

Is there a way to measure the electro-mechanical coupling of the transducer under the tank?

From the specs of the transducer, the electro-mechanical coupling coefficient is >= 60%. What is the meaning of it? Is there a way to measure it?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to the concept myself but according to search engine findings it is the efficiency of conversion from electrical energy to mechanical energy. A crude but educational approach might be to attach 2 to opposite ends of a very short liquid filled cylinder. Put a signal into 1 and see what comes out of the other. I am really winging it here. But if you are curious about it that might be a place to start.